# How to specify Tkinter correct label?

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I've made some code which has 2 functions: A clock and a countdown timer (simultaneously).

But, they show each other simultaneously as well, but what I need is only one of them at a time: For this example below, while the countdown timer starts at 60 seconds and goes to 0, it has to show on the screen, and when it reaches 0, switch back to the clock.

What is currently happening is both of them showing all the time, I just need to know how to specify something like an if countdown > 0, show countdown timer... if countdown = 0, show clock

Can anybody help me?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
root.config(cursor="none")

display = Label(root, font=('helvetica', 180, 'bold'), bg='black', fg='white')
display.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

hora = 0
tempo = 60

def clock():
    global hora
    hora = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    display['text'] = hora
    root.after(100, clock)
clock()

def countdown():
    global tempo
    display['text'] = ('{0:02d}:{1:02d}'.format(*divmod(tempo, 60)))
    if tempo > 0:
        tempo = tempo - 1
        root.after(1000, countdown)
countdown()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a single function then you won't have to worry about it fighting itself :)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
root.config(cursor="none")

display = Label(root, font=('helvetica', 180, 'bold'), bg='black', fg='white')
display.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

tempo = 60

def tick():
    global tempo

    if tempo > 0:
        # countdown mode
        display['text'] = ('{0:02d}:{1:02d}'.format(*divmod(tempo, 60)))
        tempo = tempo - 1
    else:
        # clock mode
        hora = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        display['text'] = hora
    root.after(1000, tick)

tick()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: My final project is to control both the clock and countdown timer with raspberry's gpio ports, for example: switching the screen to clock or countdown timer. With that said, i guess they would need to be in different functions. Let's suppose i use one GPI to add +1 minute to my countdown timer, when it reaches zero, it has to stay 00:00 on the screen, waiting for the next command, which could be more time or switch back to the clock. I know it's not how i asked the question, but it's just for you to know and see if there's a better way for me to do it.

Comment: No, you don't need 2 functions. You just need to make a mode variable and use that in the if check instead of the value of tempo. And have the GPIO button affect the value of the variable.